# Core data: Not saving relationships within launches

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

**UPDATE:**
I found the problem: at launch the app, to upgrade the DB, i downloaded all the activities,  deleted all db and insert the activities.
So the reference is lost.
Thanks !

---

I have a problem saving my relationship. It works fine, but when i stop the simulator and launch again the relationship is gone !
This is my code.

```
+ (BOOL) createViajeWithJson:(NSString *)responseJson dictParams:(NSDictionary *)dictParams{

    MOViaje *viaje = (MOViaje *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Viaje" inManagedObjectContext:ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    viaje.nombre = [dictParams valueForKey:@"nombreViaje"];
    viaje.destino = [dictParams valueForKey:@"destino"];
    viaje.timestamp = [NSDate date];


    NSArray *results = [responseJson JSONValue];  

    for (id object in results){
        // get the entity previously saved.
        MOActivity *tmpActivity = [MOActivity getActivityById:(NSNumber *)object];
        if (tmpActivity != nil) {
            [viaje addActivitiesViajeObject:tmpActivity];
            [tmpActivity addViajeObject:viaje];
        } 
    }       

    viaje.numActividades = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[results count]];     

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![moc save:&error]) {
        // Save failed
        NSLog(@"Core Data Save Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

///////////////////

I got the 'actvities' calling this function.

```
+ (NSArray *) getAllActivitiesFromViaje:(MOViaje *) viaje {
    NSArray *temp = [viaje.activitiesViaje allObjects] ;
    return temp;
}
```

After i create the 'viaje' and add the relationships 'activity' it returns 8, but when i stop the simulator and relaunch again, it returns 0.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: seems [CoreDataHelper commitDefaultMOC] doesn't work.

Comment: It this code:        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext;
 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![moc save:&error]) {
  // Save failed
  NSLog(@"Core Data Save Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  return NO;
 }
 return YES;

Comment: very strange, try to output error for [moc save] after saving. Maybe [mac save] is TRUE, but error is not nil

Comment: @NeverBE: thanks for the answer, but wheni print the error says 'Core Data Save Error: (null), (null)' because there are no error.

Comment: Does `ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext;` definitely return an object? Can you log that value?

Comment: @jrturton Yes, it returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `[results count]` in `viaje.numActividades`. However, in your loop you are only adding those JSON results to `viaje` which have an existing id. The number of activities which match is obviously zero.

Check if the IDs have the values you expect, and check if your `getActivityById` method works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i call getAllActivitiesFromViaje it returns **8** activities, then i stop the simulator, and this call returns **0** actvities.

Comment: The methods you describe are all hand-rolled. Just use `[viaje activities].count` to be sure you get the right value. Again, the scheme with the ID is most probably faulty.

Comment: Hi Mundi, when i call getAllActivitiesFromViaje i got an array of activities (8) and i can use them (basically listing info). Then i close the simulator, and then i got 0 activities.